# TCPDF merge two pdf

Tags: php, pdf, merge, tcpdf, concatenation

I have to merge two objects to PDF.
Its my code:

```
$obj = new Wn189PDF($first_doc);
$obj2 = new Wn189PDF($last_doc);

    $obj->Data();
    $obj2->Data();

    $obj->printPDF();
    $obj2->printPDF();
```

In my sample, TCPDF print only first doc "$obj->printPDF();".
How to concat second to first one.

Thx.

Answer (score -1):

You could try :

```
$obj = new Wn189PDF($first_doc);
$obj2 = new Wn189PDF($last_doc);

$obj->Data();
$obj2->Data();

$obj->printPDF();
$obj2->printPDF();
obj2.show();
```